# join on datatables based on NOT EQUAL

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Following code gives unique rows from two datatables. Now I want to get rows other than these. I was trying "!=" but it gives error.

```
                DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
                dtResult.Columns.Add("URL", typeof(string));
                dtResult.Columns.Add("TimeSpend", typeof(string));
                dtResult.Columns.Add("actionurl", typeof(string));
                dtResult.Columns.Add("searchedtext", typeof(string));
                dtResult.Columns.Add("datetime", typeof(string));

                var result = from dataRows1 in dtTMC.AsEnumerable()
                             join dataRows2 in dtSK.AsEnumerable()
                     // how to write condition for !=
                             on dataRows1["URL"] equals dataRows2["websiteurl"]
                             select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                {
                        dataRows1.Field<string>("URL"),
                        dataRows1.Field<string>("TimeSpend"),
                        dataRows2.Field<string>("actionurl"),
                        dataRows2.Field<string>("searchedtext"),
                        dataRows2.Field<string>("datetime")

                }, true);

                DataTable dtAll = result.CopyToDataTable();
                dtAll.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ only supports equality joins, there's not a way to use a different operator in the join itself

However, you can accomplish this using a where clause.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx):
Non-Equijoins
You can perform non-equijoins, cross joins, and other custom join operations by using multiple from clauses to introduce new sequences independently into a query. For more information, see How to: [Perform Custom Join Operations (C# Programming Guide).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882533.aspx)